# Inherit a class to remove a property and change method logic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance

The following class is used in an ASP.NET application to read currencies from a database result set and add them up (e.g. show totals in US Dollars plus show totals in GB Pounds).  It works in the following manner:

1. Read currency ID value
2. If currency ID exists already, increase the total for that currency
3. If currency ID does not exist, add it to the list with its value
4. Next

It works well using the `CurrencyID` property as the differentiator between each unique currency.  However, it has now become apparent that `IsoCurrencySymbol` is also unique for each currency by default, and so `CurrencyID` is not actually needed.

So... I was wondering if it would be possible to inherit from this class and remove any reference to `CurrencyID`, therefore making the `CompareTo` method use `IsoCurrencySymbol` instead.

The trick is to leave the existing class as it is used extensively, but introduce a modified version without `CurrencyID` being needed.  Is this possible to do please?

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class CurrencyCounter

    <Serializable()> _
    Private Class CurrencyType
        Implements IComparable

        Public IsoCurrencySymbol As String
        Public CurrencySymbol As String
        Public CurrencyID As Int16
        Public Amount As Decimal

        Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements System.IComparable.CompareTo
            If Not TypeOf (obj) Is CurrencyType Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("Object is not a currency type")
            Else
                Dim c2 As CurrencyType = CType(obj, CurrencyType)
                Return Me.CurrencyID.CompareTo(c2.CurrencyID)
            End If
        End Function

    End Class

    Private _Currencies As List(Of CurrencyType)

    Public Sub New()
        _Currencies = New List(Of CurrencyType)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddStructToList(CurrencyID As Integer, IsoCurrencySymbol As String, CurrencySymbol As String, Amount As Decimal)
        If IsoCurrencySymbol <> String.Empty AndAlso Amount > 0 Then
            Dim s As New CurrencyType
            s.CurrencyID = CurrencyID
            s.IsoCurrencySymbol = IsoCurrencySymbol
            s.CurrencySymbol = CurrencySymbol
            s.Amount = Amount
            _Currencies.Add(s)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(CurrencyID As Integer, IsoCurrencySymbol As String, CurrencySymbol As String, Amount As Decimal)
        Dim ct As CurrencyType = _Currencies.Find(Function(obj) obj.CurrencyID = CurrencyID)
        If ct IsNot Nothing Then
            ct.Amount += Amount
        Else
            AddStructToList(CurrencyID, IsoCurrencySymbol, CurrencySymbol, Amount)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clear()
        _Currencies.Clear()
    End Sub

    Public Function Count() As Integer
        Return _Currencies.Count
    End Function

    Public Function RenderTotals() As String
        ' ...
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.  The whole point of inheritance it to ensure that all derived classes, if nothing else, at least share the same public interface as their base class.  If you are removing a property, then it doesn't share the same interface and is therefore incompatible and not a candidate for inheritance.

If you can't say that the *derived class is  a type of the base class*, then you can't use inheritance.  For instance, I can say that an automobile is a type of vehicle, therefore, if I had an automobile class, I could have it inherit from a vehicle class.  I can't however say that an insect is a type of vehicle.  Therefore, even if they share most things in common, I can't have an insect class inherit from a vehicle class.

The reason for this limitation is because inheritance allows you to treat an object as if it were the base type (via *type casting*).  For instance:

```
Public Sub AddPassengerToVehicle(v As Vehicle)
    v.Passengers.Add(New Passenger())
End Sub

' ...

Dim auto As New Automobile()
Dim bug As New Insect()
AddPassengerToVehicle(auto) ' Works because an automobile is a type vehicle (inherits from vehicle)
AddPassengerToVehicle(bug) ' Can't possibly work (nor should it)
```

So, if you are in a situation where you need to have a derived class that removes/hides one of the members of its base class, you are headed in the wrong direction.  In a case like that, you would need to create a whole new class which just happens to have a very similar interface, but has no direct relationship with the first class, for instance:

```
Public Class Vehicle
    Public Property Passengers As List(Of Passenger)
    Public Property MaxSpeed As Integer

    Public Function SpeedIsTooFast(speed) As Boolean
        Return (speed > MaxSpeed)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Insect
    Public Property MaxSpeed As Integer

    Public Function SpeedIsTooFast(speed) As Boolean
        Return (speed > MaxSpeed)
    End Function
End Class
```

If you want to share functionality, such as the logic in the `SpeedIsTooFast` method in the above example, then there are a couple different ways to do that.  This first would be to make *wrapper* methods which simply make calls to the other class, for instance:

```
Public Class Insect
    Private _vehicle As New Vehicle()

    Public Property MaxSpeed() As Integer
        Get
            Return _vehicle.MaxSpeed
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _vehicle.MaxSpeed = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function SpeedIsTooFast(speed) As Boolean
        Return _vehicle.SpeedIsTooFast(speed)
    End Function
End Class
```

If you do it this way, it would be best to have both classes implement the same common interface so that you can use them interchangeably when necessary, for instance:

```
Public Interface ISelfPoweredMovingThing
    Property MaxSpeed As Integer
    Function SpeedIsTooFast(speed As Integer) As Boolean
End Interface
```

Another option would be to break out the common functionality into a third class and then use that class as the base for the other two, for instance:

```
Public Class SelfPoweredMovingThing
    Public Property MaxSpeed As Integer

    Public Function SpeedIsTooFast(speed) As Boolean
        Return (speed > MaxSpeed)
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Vehicle
    Inherits SelfPoweredMovingThing

    Public Property Passengers As List(Of Passenger)
End Class

Public Class Insect
    Inherits SelfPoweredMovingThing

    ' Anything else specific only to insects...
End Class
```

Comment: Hi Steven.  That's a really good answer.  Thanks very much for taking the time to break it down to my layman level :-)